# If $ f : S^n \to R^n $ satisfies $f(-x)=-f(x)$ for all $x \in S^n $,then there exists $ y \in S^n $ with $f(y)=0 $

Tags: algebraic-topology

If $ f : S^n \to R^n $ satisfies $f(-x)=-f(x)$ for all $x \in S^n $,then there exists $ y \in S^n $ with $f(y)=0 $

This is a problem from Rotman's Algebraic Topology book.
I think I have to use Borsuk-Ulam theorem.But I am unable to solve this.

Comment: What does the Borsuk-Ulam Theorem say?

Comment: Did you forget any hypothesis about $f$ like continuity?

Comment: @ajotatxe
That is the problem. If $f $ is continuous then this is straight forward from Borsuk-Ulam theorem.
but in question it is not mentioned that $f $ is continuous

Comment: @SaikatBasu If $f$ isn’t assumed to be continuous, then the statement is obviously false. Just partition $S^n$ into antipodal sets $S^n = T \sqcup -T$ and take any function $f \colon T → ℝ^n$ with no zeros. Then extend it to $S^n$ such that $f(-x) = -f(x)$ $∀x ∈ T$.

Comment: It's common in topology to implicitly assume that all maps are continuous (or to restrict 'map' to mean 'continuous map').

Answer (score 1):

I think the author must have missed out the word 'continuous' for convenience, as is customary in algebraic topology.  You should assume $f$ is continuous, and then, as you point out, it follows from the Borsuk-Ulam Theorem.

If $f$ is not continuous, the result is false.  For example, embed $S^n$ into $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ in the standard way and consider the function $f\colon S^n\to \mathbb R^n$ given by
$$
f(x_1,\dots,x_{n+1})=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \text{sgn}(x_i)/2^i\right)\vec{e_1}
$$

where
$$
\text{sgn}(x)=\begin{cases}
1 & x>0\\
-1 & x<0\\
0 & x=0
\end{cases}
$$
and $\vec{e_1}$ is any non-zero vector in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$.

Obviously, $f(-x)=-f(x)$ for all $x$.  You can check for yourself that $f(x_1,\dots,x_{n+1})=0$ if and only if $x_1=\dots=x_{n+1}=0$ and this never holds in the sphere.